# Pandas tocsv() function parameter sep add double quote on my data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to save my dataframe to a txt file using the tocsv() function, but then some of my data come up with quotation mark, some don't. What is causing pandas to add quotation mark on my data and is there anyway to remove it?

Here's the dataframe

```
0     0.jpg     Crinoid - unstalked
1     1.jpg     Crinoid - unstalked
2     2.jpg     Crinoid - unstalked
3     3.jpg      Holothuria - other
4     4.jpg  Urchin - regular other
5     5.jpg        Seastars - other
6     6.jpg     Crinoid - unstalked
7     7.jpg                   Worms
8     8.jpg                   Worms
9     9.jpg                   Worms
10   10.jpg                   Worms
```

And here's my file after I save it:

```
0.jpg "Crinoid - unstalked"
1.jpg "Crinoid - unstalked"
2.jpg "Crinoid - unstalked"
3.jpg "Holothuria - other"
4.jpg "Urchin - regular other"
5.jpg "Seastars - other"
6.jpg "Crinoid - unstalked"
7.jpg Worms
8.jpg Worms
9.jpg Worms
10.jpg Worms
```

The line I used to save the file

```
label.to_csv('t.txt', header=False, index=False, sep=" ", doublequote= False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes are added whenever a data point contains the separator. In this case, space " ". You can change the separator, remove all the spaces in the data or have the quotes.

In other case, the syntax of the CSV file is not parsable because the interpretation of the space character is ambiguous.

Possibly using "\t" (a tab) as a separator could be a good solution for you.

Just specify: `sep='\t'`